# npm SDK peer dependency

Tags: npm, sdk, dependencies

i want to ask on specific problem

We have SDK library (on local gitlab), which contains some JS files and it contains all packages as React, Redux, Typescript... defined in package.json as "dependency" and "peerDependency"

This library is included into new project as dependency and new project is using SDK libraries and their versions defined in SDK package.json file.
 React, Redux all included (used as imported module) into files is exported right

But problem is, when typescript or some @types/* package is added

MPM not install that packages and tslint-loader of course throw error, that typescript is not installed.

Any advice, how to properly add peerDependencies into package.json file and specially for SDK library?

Many thx for any advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm facing the same problem. I'm developing a framework module for angular projects and define the required angular packages as peerDependencies.

During development typescript can't resolve the packages (eg. '@angular/core').

My current solution for this problem is to add the peerDependencies also as devDependency so it gets installed. But I consider this more as a workaround.

Is there a better solution for this?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem. Now i have same problem with my project.

Comment: @mehmetbaran i think we moved all packages into the "dependencies" so there wasn't any package in devDependencies